# Is this another way of instantiation in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and was attempting to use [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basics) in a WPF project.  Unfortunately, I got lost on the first example and I can't find any other references to the approach.  To be honest, I'm not even sure I'm searching with the correct terms.

Is the second statement the same as the first?

And when would you use one over the other?

**The method I am familiar with:**

```
SeriesCollection seriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();
```

**The code I am struggling to understand:**

```
void MyMethod() 
{
    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection { };
}
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
```

Comment: One is a field, initialized where declared, the other is a property, initialized in the constructor using collection initializer syntax (but without providing any initial elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method declared a class variable and assigns a new object to it.

The second method assigns a new object to a declared property in the class. There is a shorter form of this type which would look like this:

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; } = new SeriesCollection();
```

There is a difference between a member variable and a property, otherwise it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: beware this type of initialization only works on the latest versions  of .net

Comment: @GeorgeSarcasmGod It requires the latest C# language version, but will run on older versions of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

There are three syntaxes for initialising objects.

There's the constructor call syntax:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new A(123);
```

There's the object initialisation syntax:

The code

```
var a = new A { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 };
```

Is shorthand for:

```
var a = new A();
a.Foo = 1;
a.Bar = 2;
```

For the most part it is carried out exactly like that (so the empty constructor is called first, then the properties are set) with the exception of anonymous types (where a hidden constructor is what is actually hit).

You can even combine the two:

```
var a = new A(123){ Foo = 1 };
```

You are allowed to leave out the `()` if you use the `{}` but don't have too.

The third way is the collection instantiation syntax:

```
var l = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var l = new List<int>();
l.Add(1);
l.Add(2);
l.Add(3);
```

You can do this on any type that both implements `IEnumerable` and has an appropriate public `Add()` method.

Again, this can be combined with the constructor `()` but you can leave out the `()` if they are empty.

In the case of a type that had both settable properties and also implemented `IEnumerable` and had at least one public `Add()` method, then an empty `{}` is ambiguous as to whether it's the object initialiser or a collection initialiser, but since an object initialiser that sets no properties and a collection initialiser that adds no elements have the same result, it's an ambiguity that doesn't matter, and is allowed.

As a matter of style, I'd generally recommend against the empty `{}` in favour of the empty `()`, but if it's a type you are more often initialising with `{}` then the empty `{}` can seem more in keeping with the rest of your code.